# C++, OOP, operator overloading errors?

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, operator-keyword

When I try using the `+` and `*`operators for both of my classes, I get errors.
For overloading `+` I get: `Invalid operands of types nod* and nod* to binary operator+.`
Same for `*`,and for the overloaded operators in my matrice class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class nod
{
    friend class matrice;
    float re,im;
    int i,j;
    nod *next;
    public:
    void setcomp(float x, float y)
    {
        re=x;
        im=y;
    }
    void setrand(int rand)
    {
        i=rand;
    }
    void setcol(int col)
    {
        j=col;
    }
    void setnext(nod *temp)
    {
        next=temp;
    }
    float getre()
    {
        return re;
    }
    float getim()
    {
        return im;
    }
    int getrand()
    {
        return i;
    }
    int getcol()
    {
        return j;
    }
    nod *getnext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, nod *z);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, nod *z);
    nod* operator+(nod *z);
    nod* operator*(nod *z);
    void operator=(nod *z);
};

istream& operator>>(istream &in, nod *z)
{
    in>>z->re>>z->im;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, nod *z)
{
    if(z->im<0)
    out<<z->re<<"-"<<z->im<<"i";
    else
    out<<z->re<<"+"<<z->im<<"i";
    return out;
}

nod* nod::operator+(nod *z)
{
    nod *temp;
    temp->re=re+z->re;
    temp->im=im+z->im;
    return temp;
}

nod* nod::operator*(nod *z)
{
    nod *temp;
    temp->re=(re*z->re)-(im*z->im);
    temp->im=(re*z->im)-(im*z->re);
    return temp;
}

void nod::operator=(nod *z)
{
    re=z->re;
    im=z->im;
}

class matrice
{
    nod *prim,*ultim;
    int n,m;
    public:
    matrice()
    {
        prim=NULL;
        ultim=prim;
    }
    int getl()
    {
        return n;
    }
    int getc()
    {
        return m;
    }
    nod* getprim()
    {
        return prim;
    }
    nod* getultim()
    {
        return ultim;
    }
    void adaugare(nod *p,int i,int j);
    void cautare1(nod *c, int i, int j);
    void cautare2(matrice a, nod *c, int i, int j);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in,matrice a);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,matrice a);
    void afisare();
    matrice& operator+(matrice b);
    matrice& operator*(matrice b);
}temp;

void matrice::adaugare(nod *p,int i,int j)
{
    if(prim==NULL)
        {
            prim = new nod;
            prim->re=p->re;
            prim->im=p->im;
            prim->setrand(i);
            prim->setcol(j);
            prim->setnext(NULL);
            ultim = prim;
        }
        else
        {
            nod* temp = new nod;
            temp->re=p->re;
            temp->im=p->im;
            temp->setrand(i);
            temp->setcol(j);
            temp->setnext(NULL);
            ultim->setnext(temp);
            ultim = temp;
        }
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in,matrice a)
{
    float x,y;
    int i,j;
    nod *p;
    p=new nod;
    in>>a.n>>a.m;
    for(i=1;i<=a.n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=a.m;j++)
        {
            in>>p;
            a.adaugare(p,i,j);
        }
    }
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,matrice a)
{
    nod *p=a.getprim();
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=a.n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=a.m;j++)
        {
            out<<p;
        }
        out<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}

void matrice::cautare1(nod *c, int i, int j)
{
    c=prim;
    while(c!=NULL)
    {
        if((c->getrand()==i)&&(c->getcol()==j))
        break;
        c=c->getnext();
    }
}

void cautare2(matrice a, nod *c, int i, int j)
{
    c=a.getprim();
    while(c!=NULL)
    {
        if((c->getrand()==i)&&(c->getcol()==j))
        break;
        c=c->getnext();
    }
}

void matrice::afisare()
{
    int i,j;
    nod *p=prim;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        {
            cout<<p;
            p=prim->getnext();
        }
    }
}

matrice& matrice::operator+(matrice b)
{
    nod *prim2=b.prim;
    nod *p1=prim, *p2=prim2, *ps;
    ps=new nod;
    int i,j;
    matrice s;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        {
            ps=p1+p2;
            s.adaugare(ps,i,j);
            p1=p1->getnext();
            p2=p2->getnext();
        }
    }
    return s;
}

matrice& matrice::operator *(matrice b)
{
    matrice p;
    nod *p1=new nod,*p2=new nod,*q=new nod;
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=b.m;j++)
        {
            q->setcomp(0,0);
            q->setrand(i);
            q->setcol(j);
            p.adaugare(q,i,j);
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=b.m;j++)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=m;k++)
            {
                cautare2(p,q,i,j);
                cautare1(p1,i,k);
                cautare2(b,p2,k,j);
                q=p1*p2;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}

void submat(matrice a, matrice &b,int n, int x, int y)
{
    int i,j,k=0;
    nod *q;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if((i!=x)&&(j!=y))
            {
                k++;
                if(k==n)
                {
                    k=1;
                    x++;
                }
                cautare2(a,q,i,j);
                b.adaugare(q,x,k);

            }
}

nod *determinant(matrice a,int n)
{
    matrice b;
    nod *temp,*c,*d,*oarecare,*p1,*p2,*p3,*p4;
    int i;
    float real,imag,real2,imag2;
    temp=new nod;
    temp->setcomp(0.0,0.0);
    temp->setrand(0);
    temp->setcol(0);
    if(n==1)
    {
        cautare2(a,oarecare,1,1);
        temp->setcomp(oarecare->getre(),oarecare->getim());
    }
    else
    {
        if(n==2)
        {
            cautare2(a,p1,1,1);
            cautare2(a,p2,2,2);
            temp=p1*p2;
            cautare2(a,p3,1,2);
            cautare2(a,p4,2,1);
            temp=temp-p3*p4;
        }
            else
            {
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    submat(a,b,n,1,i);
                    c->setcomp(pow(-1,i+1),0);
                    c->setrand(0);
                    c->setcol(0);
                    cautare2(a,p1,1,i);
                    c=c*p1;
                    d=temp;
                    c=c*determinant(b,n-1);
                    temp=d+c;
                }
            }
    }
    return temp;
}

void inversa(matrice a, nod *&z)
{
    nod *p1,*p2,*temp,*y;
    matrice b,tr,c;
    int i,j,n;
    n=(a.getultim())->getrand();
    float real, imag;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            cautare2(a,p1,j,i);
            tr.adaugare(p1,i,j);
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            submat(tr,b,n,i,j);
            y->setcomp(pow(-1,i+j),0);
            c.adaugare(y,i,j);
            temp=determinant(b,n-1);
            cautare2(c,p2,i,j);
            p2=p2*temp;
            real=z->getre()/(pow(z->getre(),2)+pow(z->getim(),2));
            imag=z->getim()/(pow(z->getre(),2)+pow(z->getim(),2));
            temp->setcomp(real, imag);
            p2=p2*temp;
        }
    }
    c.afisare();
}

int main()
{
    ifstream f("mat.txt");
    matrice a,b;
    f>>a>>b;
    cout<<"Matricea A:\n"<<a;
    cout<<"\nMatricea B:\n"<<b;
    cout<<a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you'll get an exception if running this code - the operator overload methods are referencing garbage poitners... the `nod* temp;` is not initialized at all - check your code...

Comment: This is not a debugging service.

Comment: When asking this type of questions you should post the minimal portion of your code that's relevant to your problem. If you think it will be necessary for others to execute your code in order to help you, then take time to write a shorter complete program that compiles and still exposes your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly your code:

```
nod* nod::operator+(nod *z)
{
    nod *temp;
    temp->re=re+z->re;
    temp->im=im+z->im;
    return temp;
}
```

1. nod *temp is wrong, temp is not an object, is just a pointer with no memory allocated to it.
2. when overloading operator+ you need to return a new object, not a pointer.
3. parameter of operator+ should be reference to an object, not a pointer to it

Having this in mind, i would rewrite the code like this:

```
nod nod::operator+(const nod &z)
{
    nod temp;
    temp.re=this->re+z.re;
    temp.im=this->im+z.im;
    return temp;
}
```

Here you will find some good examples: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html